# Find the smallest $n$ and $m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $F$ is a finite field  with $q$ element and the numbers  $k$ and $s$ are given. I want to build a matrix over $F$ with $n$ row  and $m$ column such that every $k$ columns of this matrix are linearly independent. Now find the smallest $n$  and $m$  in term of $s$ and $k$ and $q$ such that satisfies in my condition and also we must have $m > s $ and $m = s+n$

Comment: Does every $k$ columns are linearly independent mean that every set of $k$ columns is linearly independent, or that blocks of $k$ columns are independent?

Comment: It means every set of k columns are linearly independent